# Select rows from one table with joined only last row from another

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (match, player and goal), 
and I need to display all matches, but only with the name of the last player who scored.
I know that I need to join my tables, but I don't know how.

here is my database diagram:

[database diagram http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/582/8gqj.jpg](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/582/8gqj.jpg)

Comment: I know, but I am trying it for 5 days and I dont understand how to do this. I know how to display it but only with first row.. no last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can do

```
SELECT m.id, m.date, p.name, g.goal FROM match m
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT max(id) gid,id_match FROM goal GROUP BY id_match ) 
            lastgoal ON lastgoal.id_match=m.id
  LEFT JOIN goal g   ON g.id=lastgoal.gid
  LEFT JOIN player p ON p.id=g.id_player
```

The first subquery (with a `GROUP BY`) finds the last goal of each game on the assumption that it has the highest id  (entered last), the rest is straight forward joins ...

Comment: oh.. this is excelent.. thanks a lot cars10

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` mixed with `ORDER BY` to select only one item from a table, then make your join.

Comment: thanks diegoperini.. Im trying it for 5 days but with no success